# JSON_encode syntax error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, post, syntax

I have the following code:

`window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/" + <?php json_encode($row["item"]); ?>;`

That's causing a `;` syntax error. I understand why - it's because `$row["item"]` doesn't exist until it's `echo`'ed from another page (using `echo ".$row["item"].";`), so html sees it as `window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/" + ;`

I've been attempting to fix this for a while, and thought `json_encode` may do the job, but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Can't you move the `+` into the PHP code, and use a PHP conditional operator to output `+` *and* the value if the value exists, otherwise output an empty string?

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm trying this `<?php echo "+"; if (".$row["item"].") { echo ".$row["item"]."} else {""} ?>` but that doesn't work (it prevents the page from loading)

Comment: I can't understand why you need to print the value when it doesn't exist. Unless you're unaware of [flow control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/<?php echo $row["item"]; ?>";
```

Now, if `$row["item"]` is undefined, you shouldn't be getting the `" + ;` JavaScript error any longer.